# Removing rear hub end caps (Mavic Allroad Pro)

Tags: wheels, conversion, through-axle

I've just bought a Mavic Allroad Pro wheelset and I want to convert the rear hub from 12x142 to 10x135 configuration. I bought the 10x135 adapters (highlighted in red in the attached image, it's a section of Mavic manual) and I need to remove the original endcaps. I tried pulling them by hand but they don't move at all and I'm afraid of damaging something by using too much force. What is the correct procedure to remove the endcaps? Anyone knows? Couldn't find anything on Mavic site about this.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to use force to get those guys off.

If you can wrap the cap with a rag and then grip it with a pair of pliers you should be able to pull it straight off. It will take some effort.

Comment: I somewhat agree. In my experience, these caps will usually come off with a screwdriver pried underneath each side, lifting millimetre by millimetre on each side. This worked on my Mav' wheelset and caused no damage. Your method will work, but sounds a little barbaric. If you have no intention to reuse them, your method will certainly be the fastest route.

Comment: @yollooool fastest simplest method. I've done it dozens of time here at the shop. If you're careful and don't scratch it, this way is superior.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap end cap in a couple layers of insulating tape, tightly bolt on a correct size p clamp (the clamps you use to fix racks etc to frames without mudguard eyes) use mole grips on the p clamp, gently pull off cap, hey presto!!

Answer (score 1):

See

https://tech.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data/mavic_tech.php?display=product&family=1014&subfamily=0&macronu=29672

For Allroad hub technical documents.

I removed the non driveside through axle adapter OK with a flat end screwdriver.

I then wrapped a rubber strip from a light bracket around the the driveside through axle adapter, cable tied the rubber strip around the spacer, then gently gripped it in the jaws of a bench top vice. The adapter came off fine by pulling the wheel up from the vice. NB when the adapter comes out there is a wider plastic seal on the inner edge a little bit wider than the protruding metal. This is normal according to the technical document see above.component #14.

Answer (score 0):

If the wheelset is brand new, you can grab the hub body in your hand and pull it off. I just did that now, nothing got hurt